# clean up word pasted apostrophe and other special characters

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've looked around and have not found a solid solution to this.  Is there a way to replace word pasted apostrophes and other special characters coming from a text editor (radeditor)?  When I attempt to send them in an email, these characters are being replaced with a ? question mark.  I would prefer not to manually replace every possible special character, unless there is a know list somewhere.

Comment: I would think you could change the encoding or perform any post-processing with the contents of the text box like you could with a default one. Can you describe in more detail what issues you're facing? Is this a radeditor-specific issue, or are you asking about string encoding and sanitizing in general?

Comment: @neontapir This is the process that is occurring.  Users are entering text into a radeditor and sometimes paste and copy text from a word document.  The application then saves the entered text to the sql server.  Later, another application retrieves the text from the sql server and sends it out in an email... Somewhere along the process, I need to capture the text and clean up microsoft word special characters.  It is displaying correctly everywhere except in  a sent email.

Comment: Agreed, my point was that you could experience the same problem with an ordinary text box, couldn't you? If so, you might reach a wider audience for your question by removing the `radeditor` tag.

Comment: what encoding do you use for sending mails ?

Comment: @AntonioBakula System.Text.Encoding.Default

Comment: RadEditor saves text in encoding used on the web, the same encoding must be used when sending mails. Your problem may be caused by different encodings. Use UTF-8 in both cases if possible

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".